# Joining 2 or more sql queries using outer join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

Im trying to return results from 5 sql statement using 'outer join' , i want the stock_id, stock_name and sum of sales each day for the past 5 days to be returned as separate columns. How can I structure it?

```
select s1.sid as sid,s1.sname as sname, sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5
from
(
 select stock.id as sid, stock.Name as sname, sum(orders.Quantity) as 'sum1' from orders inner join stock on `Stock_id`= stock.id where  orders.Created_at Like '2020-05-16%' group by Stock_id asc
) 
as s1
full outer join
(
select stock.id as sid,stock.Name as sname, sum(orders.Quantity) as 'sum2' from orders inner join stock on `Stock_id`= stock.id where  orders.Created_at Like '2020-05-17%' group by Stock_id asc
)
as s2 on s1.sid=s2.sid 
outer join
(
select stock.id as sid,stock.Name as sname, sum(orders.Quantity) as 'sum3' from orders inner join stock on `Stock_id`= stock.id where  orders.Created_at Like '2020-05-18%' group by Stock_id asc
) as s3 on s1.sid=s3.sid 
outer join
( 
select stock.id as sid,stock.Name as sname,sum(orders.Quantity) as 'sum4' from orders inner join stock on `Stock_id`= stock.id where  orders.Created_at Like '2020-05-19%' group by Stock_id asc
)as s4 on s1.sid=s4.sid 
outer join
(
select stock.id as sid,stock.Name as sname, sum(orders.Quantity) as 'sum5' from orders inner join stock on `Stock_id`= stock.id where  orders.Created_at Like '2020-05-20%' group by Stock_id asc
)as s5 on s1.sid=s5.sid
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` cannot be followed by `ASC`.

Comment: what if i want it in ascending order?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'full outer join
(
select stock.id as sid,stock.Name as sname, sum(orders.Quantit' at line 7

Comment: Thats the error i get

Comment: "what if i want it in ascending order?" -- Then use `ORDER BY`. But you can't use `ORDER BY` wihtout limiting rows in a subquery. But that's another ball game.

Comment: The OP seems to have MySQL, but incorrectly tagged the question as "oracle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.id as sid, s.Name as sname,
       sum(case when date(o.created_at) = '2020-05-16' then o.Quantity end) as sum1,
       sum(case when date(o.created_at) = '2020-05-17' then o.Quantity end) as sum2,
       sum(case when date(o.created_at) = '2020-05-18' then o.Quantity end) as sum3,
       sum(case when date(o.created_at) = '2020-05-19' then o.Quantity end) as sum4,
       sum(case when date(o.created_at) = '2020-05-20' then o.Quantity end) as sum5
from orders o inner join
     stock s
     on o.Stock_id = s.id 
group by s.id;
```

This is much simpler and requires no finicky `join`s or subqueries.  Also, it fixes the date arithmetic.

Comment: In MySQL you can use `DATE()` instead of `TRUNC()`.

Comment: Yes date() works fine. Thanks @TheImpaler  and @ Gordon Linoff. This works for me.

Comment: @Mariwa . . . MySQL doesn't support `full join` so your attempted solution wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff how would you convert the null values to zero with the query above? i.e. coalesce(column_name,0) as 'name' or ifnull(column_name,0)as 'name'

Comment: Question open to anybody.

Comment: @Mariwa . . . Just add `else 0` to each of the `case` expressions.